# AWS SAM give lambda access to dynamodb and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sam

When I run sam validate I get error for Policies part. If I keep one of the policy for either S3 or DynamoDB then it works.

why this Policies: part is invalid ?

```
MResponseFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: mresponse/
      Handler: app.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        MResponse:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test
            Method: GET
      Policies:
        DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
          TableName: pending-response
        S3CrudPolicy:
          BucketName: mresponse
```

Answer (score 1):

The Policies property needs to be either a string or an array of strings. (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html#sam-function-policies)
This explains why it worked if you had only one, because then it was just a string. but if you have more than one policy you need to format it as an array.
I think something like this should work:

```
MResponseFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: mresponse/
      Handler: app.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        MResponse:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /test
            Method: GET
      Policies:
      - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
        TableName: pending-response
      - S3CrudPolicy:
        BucketName: mresponse
```